# Kafka jaas verify failed on Flink cluster

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, apache-beam, jaas

I am running into a very strange issue that

```
Could not find a "KafkaClient" entry in the JAAS configuration. System property "java.security.auth.login.config" is /etc/kafka/kafka_sink_jaas.conf
```

on a single node Apache Flink cluster when i consume record from kafka using Apache Beam KafkaIO. The JAAS file contains 'KafkaClient', but the Flink cluster cannot find the entry. Does anyone know the reason caused?

Comment: When i run the application on flink local machine, This issue does not exist! So i guess the reason is about to the flink cluster!

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this issue. It's caused by the flink cluster kerberos configuration. Just need to set some config on flink-conf.yaml can make it work fine!

The settings is below:

```
security.kerberos.login.use-ticket-cache: false 
security.kerberos.login.keytab: /etc/kafka/kafka.keytab
security.kerberos.login.principal: kafka@HADOOP.COM
security.kerberos.login.contexts: Client,KafkaClient
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you few things to try.

Set KAFKA_OPTS

export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_sink_jaas.conf"

Add following to your code

```
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "/etc/kafka/kafka_sink_jaas.conf")
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "/etc/krb5.conf")
System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", false)
System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false")
```

Hope this would help.

Comment: I have tried your suggest, but cannot solve my issue！

Answer (score 0):

While running Flink locally i used this jaas config file. The below does not work in cluster mode as mentioned by Fred.

```
    KafkaClient {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    username="MyUserId"
    password="MyPwd";
    };

security.kerberos.login.use-ticket-cache: false 
security.kerberos.login.keytab: /etc/kafka/kafka.keytab
security.kerberos.login.principal: kafka@HADOOP.COM
security.kerberos.login.contexts: Client,KafkaClient
```

If we use kerberos settings is this correct ?
    security.kerberos.login.principal: MyUserId

Also to create a keytab file i used klist. It always seems to be adding a domain name with user e.g. MyUserId@somedomain.com. Is there a way to avoid this ?

Comment: The kafka.keytab is kafka user‘s keytab file.If you use your keytab, you should set security.kerberos.login.principal: MyUserId.And the security.kerberos.login.contexts just have Client.